# Artifactory Repositories are not populated in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, artifactory

I have

Jenkins running at localhost:8080 with Artifactory 3.4.1 plugin installed in it.

Artifactory running at http://localhost:8081

I have created local repository in Artifactory with name Jenkins-Integration and Jenkins-Snapshot. I have also created one user name Jenkins with admin access and give a permission to access above repositories.

I have created one Maven project in Jenkins and under "Post-build Actions", I have select "Deploy builds to Artifactory". I have name Artifactory Server as "http://localhost:8081/artifactory".

Now the problem is that "Target release repository" and "Target snapshot repository" are not populated. when I click on "Refresh Repositories" button then it goes in infinite loop and does not load anything. I am using the same username which I have created in Artifactory.

I do not understand that why it is not populated even when I followed all the steps. Please let me know where the problem is?

Thanks,
Jatin

Comment: Can you please look at the web browser console when you click on refresh? What do you see there?

Comment: I do not see any error in the console. Actually nothing is happening at all

Comment: How about the network tab? Don't you see the request there?

Comment: Please also make sure that clicking on the "Test connection" button of your Artifactory server in "Manage Jenkins > Configure System" returns "Found Artifactory x.x.x".

Comment: Test connection is working fine and nothing suspicious in the network tab also.